# Dismissed notifications come back

Tags: notifications, lg, lg-g6

I'm having an issue on my LG G6 where if I swipe to dismiss a notification (such as a text message or Tweetcaster mention), sometime later (an hour, maybe more) it will come back. Only if I tap on the notification, and go all the way through to the app, does it register as properly dismissed.

There doesn't seem to be a "repeat notifications" in Accessibility which would cause this. Any other likely causes?